# terraform: how to add a block of secret_environment_variables in google_cloudfunctions_function

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am new to terraform. I am trying to deploy a cloud function with multi secrets exposed as environment variables. It fails however I tried it. My code snippet is below.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name        = "function-test"
  description = "My function"
  runtime     = "python310"
  ...
  entry_point                  = "helloGET"
 
  environment_variables = {
    MY_ENV_VAR = "my-env-var-value"
  }

  secret_environment_variables = [  
    {
      key     = "envID"
      secret  = var.envID
      version = "latest"
    },
    {
      key     = "client_id"
      secret  = var.client_id
      version = "latest"
    },
    {
      key     = "client_secret"
      secret  = var.client_secret
      version = "latest"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then the terraform plan produced the following errors:

> Error: Unsupported argument
> │
> │   on resources.tf line 378, in resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "cloud_function":
> │  378:   secret_environment_variables = [
> │
> │ An argument named "secret_environment_variables" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "secret_environment_variables"?

What is the right syntax, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation [1], the `secret_environment_variables` is a block:

> The `secret_environment_variables` block supports:

That means that it is not a list, which is denoted with square brackets, or what you have been trying to do. This should fix it:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name        = "function-test"
  description = "My function"
  runtime     = "python310"
  ...
  entry_point                  = "helloGET"
 
  environment_variables = {
    MY_ENV_VAR = "my-env-var-value"
  }

  secret_environment_variables {  
      key     = "envID"
      secret  = var.envID
      version = "latest"
  }

  secret_environment_variables {
      key     = "client_id"
      secret  = var.client_id
      version = "latest"
  }

  secret_environment_variables {
      key     = "client_secret"
      secret  = var.client_secret
      version = "latest"
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function#nested_secret_environment_variables

Comment: Hi Marko thanks for the pointer. But i did spent a few hours on that terraform page, and could not find if i missed anything from it. Have you got it working in the past?

Comment: Not really, but I have spent some time working with terraform so I kind of know how to understand the documentation for different providers. :) Anyway, it says it's a block, which is different to a list. So if you see list mentioned, that means square brackets. :)

Comment: I tried with different syntax: here list a few: secret_environment_variables = [{key=.. secret= version=...},{}] and secret_environment_variables[{},{}]

Comment: ha, I tried and it worked. Many thanks Marko!

Comment: this is a very bad idea from Terraform. how are we suppose to create reusable modules which accept different secret variables

Comment: It's not a terraform idea, rather the way API is created on GCP side. However, you could utilize `dynamic` blocks for same/similar types of configuration.

Answer (score -1):

In the second generation of Google Cloud Functions, secrets are accessed using secret_environment_variables instead of environment_variables.

So it should be:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "function"
```