# terraform: Error while adding "secret_environment_variables" in google_cloudfunctions_function resource

Tags: google-cloud-functions, terraform-provider-gcp

I've tried the below tf code for cloudFunction.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "dbex-function" {
  name        = "function-test"
  description = "My function"
  runtime     = "python39"
  ....
  entry_point  = "dbex_conn"

  environment_variables = {
  TARGET = "test.com"
}

secret_environment_variables {  
  key     = "KEY"
  secret  = key
  version = "latest"
 }
}
```

But, I'm getting the below error in terraform validate.

```
Error: Unsupported block type

on cloudFunction.tf line 133, in resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "dbex-function":
133:   secret_environment_variables {

Blocks of type "secret_environment_variables" are not expected here.

validate failed, post status
```

Don't know why it's giving such an error.

- **Please note:**
  The terraform version for me is : 0.14.11 and google provider version is : v3.90.1

I've checked the similar problem here: [terraform: how to add a block of secret_environment_variables in google_cloudfunctions_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127620/terraform-how-to-add-a-block-of-secret-environment-variables-in-google-cloudfun)

But this is not working for my case.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the provider version you are using, there is no block with secret_environment_variables in v3.90.1.

Upgrade your provider version to atleast 4.2 to access secret_environment_variables block.

Below is the document you can refer to:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/4.20.0/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function

Comment: Thanks @aayush-mohta.
It worked after upgrading the provider version.